# Getting variables from another python file WITHOUT importing

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a cleanup script for my jenkins server. Without going into too many details, I want to get a variable from a file in each docroot and match it against something, in a for loop.

So, as seemingly every single google result told me to, I tried adding the docroot to the sys.path.append(docroot), then used imp to find the module, imported it using

```
imp.find_module('python_vars')
from python_vars import git_branch
```

and used the variable.

The problem here is that it works for the first one, but then it's already loaded, and doesn't change in the loop. So I'm trying to remove the docroot from the sys.path at the end of each iteration, and then reload the module on the next one using

```
reload('python_vars')
from python_vars import git_branch
```

This gives me a 'reload() argument must be module'. And

```
reload(python_vars)
from python_vars import git_branch
```

gives me 'NameError: name 'python_vars' is not defined'

Tbh, this seems like a horrible way to do it, is there not an easier way to get a variable from a file?

In php I would simply do something like 
include(docroot) in the loop and it would overwrite the variable in memory and it's done.

Here's the full loop, which I am fully aware is rubbish, but I'm just trying stuff out for now.

```
if os.path.exists(docroot):
        sys.path.append(docroot)
        # If docroot exists need to check if it is meant to
        import imp
        try:
                imp.find_module('python_vars')
                from python_vars import git_branch
                remove_project = check_for_git_branch(docroot, git_branch)
        except ImportError:
                remove_project = True
                print 'importerror'
        try:
                imp.find_module('python_vars')
                reload(python_vars)
                from python_vars import git_branch
        except ImportError:
                print 'nope'

        sys.path.remove(docroot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate the contents of a Python file using [execfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval).

e.g. Say this is the contents `vars.py`:

```
git_branch = 'feature/awesome'
```

Then `script.py` could do:

```
execfile('./vars.py')
print git_branch
```

Of course this has just been evaluated in the global scope, which could be a bit dangerous, so a safer option would be to pass in a dict to store the globals evaluated in `vars.py`:

```
vars = {}
execfile('./vars.py',vars)
print vars['git_branch']
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to actually grab a reference to the module to be able to reload it:

```
# First:
import python_vars

# Then:
do_something_with(python_vars.git_branch)

# Later on
reload(python_vars)
```

Comment: So I would have to perhaps add in a function that does nothing to register that as a reference?

Comment: @MichaelMallett No, just import the module as I showed you. Can you post your full code? You're mentioning a loop, but I don't see one in the code you posted.

Comment: Ah apologies, when you said I needed to grab a reference I assumed that the action of passing the variable in the manner you were was doing something specific. So importing the full file, not the variable, and changing `check_for_git_branch(docroot, git_branch)` to `check_for_git_branch(docroot, python_vars.git_branch)` and then reloading is should suffice?

Comment: The loop itself is just going through a list of vhosts and grabbing the docroot from it, essentially a list of docroots where it grabs the file from.

Comment: This still seems like a fairly heavy handed way to do things tbh, can you not pull in variables in another way?

Comment: This also means that I'm left with a pyc file in the repo, that (as this script needs to be run by root) is owned by root and can't be deleted by jenkins. Surely there is a simpler way to get a single variable from another source. Adding to the sys path, loading, reloading, unsetting the path, then removing the compiled python file?? Can't be the right way

Comment: @MichaelMallett Did you consider not putting the variables in a Python file in the first place. E.g. dumping them into a `json` or `ini` file?